# s3fs: unable to access MOUNTPOINT {bucketname}: No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-s3, s3fs

I am trying to mount S3 sub-directories, using the following command:

```
s3fs -o iam_role="mediation-ocomc-lit" -o url="https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com" -o endpoint=eu-central-1 -o dbglevel=info -o curldbg -o allow_other -o use_cache=/tmp mp_umask=002 -o multireq_max=5  iotbigdatarawfilesft-lit:/InputFiles/OCOMC-mnt/ /opt/SP/users/oracle/data/input/
```

but I am stuck now with this error:

```
s3fs: unable to access MOUNTPOINT iotbigdatarawfilesft-lit:/InputFiles/OCOMC-mnt/: No such file or directory
```

I have tried a lot of fixes but with no success, actually I don't know what's the issue.

Please advise

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check if your bucket name is correct it should be something like this and also check if path "/opt/SP/users/oracle/data/input/" also exist.

```
#s3fs -o iam_role="s3fsmountingrole" -o url="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com" -o endpoint=eu-central-1 -o dbglevel=info -o curldbg -o allow_other -o use_cache=/tmp s3fs-namebucket /var/s3fs-filesystem
```

Good Luck!